# Index out of bound exception when traversing a tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, indexoutofboundsexception, tree-traversal

I'm having problems with my mini filesystem I'm creating for a homework. The current assignment is to implement the operation find which basicly finds the folder or file with the name you send in. I't works when I'm traversing through it's parents, but the tricky part is when I try to get the paths from the directorys/folders that have a pointer to either the target directory/file or a directory that is somehow a parent to the target.

Ex: Directorys /a/b/c (/c is the target) and directorys /d/e, now if /e or /d points to either /b or /c it works fine, but when I point /d to /a the output is: /d/a/c. It doesent go through /b. Any tips on how to fix this?

Updated this so that it goes through the targets parents until it reaches the parent who is being pointed to and the it goes to the pointer and goes through it's parents. However now it's throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException instead.

MiniFs class:

```
package se.kth.id1020.minifs;

import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdOut;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MiniFs implements FileSystem {

  private final INodeDirectory root;
  private HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  private int n = 0;
  private ArrayList<INodeDirectory> directoryNodes = new ArrayList<INodeDirectory>();
  private ArrayList<INodeFile> fileNodes = new ArrayList<INodeFile>();
  private HashMap<String, INodeDirectory> pointer = new HashMap<String, INodeDirectory>();

  public MiniFs() {
    root = new INodeDirectory("/");
    map.put("/",n);
  }

  @Override
  public void find (String target){
      if(!map.containsKey(target)){
          StdOut.println(target + " does not excist!");
      }
      else if(target.endsWith(".txt")){
          INodeFile targetNode = new INodeFile(target);
          int index = fileNodes.indexOf(targetNode);
          INodeDirectory parent = fileNodes.get(index).getParent();
          ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();

          path.add(root.getName());
          int cnt = 1;
          while(parent != root){
              path.add(parent.getName());
              links.add(parent.getName());
              path.add("/");
              index = directoryNodes.indexOf(parent);
              parent = directoryNodes.get(index).getParent();
              cnt++;
          }
          path.add(target);
          for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++){

              if(i > 0 && i < path.size()-1){
                  StdOut.print(path.get(cnt));
                  cnt--;
              }
              else{
                  StdOut.print(path.get(i));
              }
          }
          StdOut.println();
          path.clear();

          int targetIndex = fileNodes.indexOf(targetNode);
          for(int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++){
              parent = fileNodes.get(targetIndex).getParent();
              StdOut.println("Parent: " + parent.getName());
              path.add(root.getName());
              cnt = 1;
              while(parent.getName() != links.get(i)){
                  path.add(parent.getName());
                  path.add("/");
                  index = directoryNodes.indexOf(parent);
                  parent = directoryNodes.get(index).getParent();
                  StdOut.println("Parent W: " + parent.getName());
                  cnt++;
              }
              path.add(links.get(i));
              path.add("/");
              cnt++;
              parent = pointer.get(links.get(i));
              while(parent != root){
                  StdOut.println("Parent W2: " + parent.getName());
                  path.add(parent.getName());
                  path.add("/");
                  index = directoryNodes.indexOf(parent);
                  parent = directoryNodes.get(index).getParent();
                  cnt++;
              }
              path.add(target);
              StdOut.println("Path size: " + path.size() + " cnt: " + cnt);
              for(int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++){
                  if(j > 0 && j < path.size() - 1){
                      StdOut.print(path.get(cnt)); <---- IOOB thrown here
                      cnt--;
                  }
                  else{
                      StdOut.print(path.get(j));
                  }
              }
              path.clear();
              StdOut.println();
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Did you try debugger?

Comment: @talex yeah, and It seems that it's because when it comes to the directory that is pointing to another it traverse up and the parent for the pointing directory is root so the while-loop stops. So I need someway to go through the targets parents and when one of it's parents have a directory that points to it, it should stop and go through that one and go through it's parents

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by doing

```
int x = path.size() - 3;
for(int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++){
    if(j > 0 && j < path.size() - 1){
        StdOut.print(path.get(x));
            x--;
     }
     else{
         StdOut.print(path.get(j));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Glad you found it - please accept your answer. Also (in your question) try to avoid horizontal scrollbars - code should be 80 chars wide